# div position changing when zooming browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, css

I have a popup div, its working fine and gets popped up when i click a image, now when i zoom in or out, the popup div stays where it is as its position is absolute, when i am changing it to relative, its popping out at different place, the css and javascript are below:

**css**

```
.set_pop{
                position:absolute;
                margin-right: 50px;
                margin-top:10px;
                width:100px;
                -webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
                -moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
                box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
                border-radius:5px;
                -moz-border-radius:5px;
                -webkit-border-radius:5px;
                z-index:10;
                background-color: #ffffff;
                color:#000;
            }
```

**js**

```
 $('.settings img').live('click', function(event){
               event.stopPropagation();
                 var popup_div = $('.set_pop');
                var obj = $(this);
                var offset = obj.offset();

                var new_top = offset.top + 30;

                var new_left = offset.left;

                new_left = new_left - ( popup_div.width() / 2);
                new_left = new_left + ( obj.width() / 2);

                popup_div.css('left', new_left + 'px');
                popup_div.css('top', new_top + 'px');

                popup_div.show();
            });
```

what i need is this div to reposition it self with the source of popup in my case its image, when i am zooming in/out

thanks and regards

Comment: What version of jquery are you using? .live() is deprecated since a couple versions.

Comment: its 1.9, i have 1.8 also can use either but i think its nt cause of jquery

Comment: anybody please answer this or provide a link for similar question if known. please

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of window resizing, so you need to run the function on each time window is resized. Sample code...

```
$('.settings img').live('click', function(event){
    $('#hidid').attr('value', $(this).attr('id'));              
    showDiv(this.id);
});

window.onresize = function() {
    var id = $('#hidid').attr('value');
    showDiv(id);
};

function showDiv(id) {
    var popup_div = $('.set_pop');
    var obj = $('#'+id);
    var offset = obj.offset();

    var new_top = offset.top + 30;
    var new_left = offset.left;
    new_left = new_left - ( popup_div.width() / 2);
    new_left = new_left + ( obj.width() / 2);

    popup_div.css('left', new_left + 'px');
    popup_div.css('top', new_top + 'px');
    popup_div.show();
}
```

And html part I have take a hidden field to store the id on clicking the image... you can store it in your own way. and btw I have also use id for each image. May be it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

try with `position:fixed;` instead of `position:absolute;`. fixed position will keep the box in same. If you are using absolute that box will go up when you scroll-down the page. When using position fixed use left and right to margin. Like this

```
.set_pop{
    position:fixed;
    right: 50px;
    top:10px;
    width:100px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
    box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    z-index:10;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color:#000;
}
```